# Crash on Production Firebase Database RejectedExecution Exception and HardAssert Exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Android App getting crashed on production many times by two exceptions.

> Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (20.0.0).

further caused by:

> Caused by java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: Expected connection state disconnected, but was GettingToken
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.ConnectionUtils.hardAssert(ConnectionUtils.java:67)

and

> Non-fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@ea8d495 rejected from com.google.firebase.database.v.i0.c$a@ee619aa[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 430]

I had tried the latest version of Firebase Libraries, tried older version libraries as well but no luck.

This is only happening on production live build, so it is hard to track the cause.

Someone help is highly appreciated. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. No solution for now. I just noticed that all of my occurrences of the error belong to Samsung devices.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm still facing same issue even with latest version of firebase bom 29.0.0